# Is there a way to print a keys and values of dictionaries one in each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print my keys and values in my dictionary one in each line.

I've tried using /n or pressing enter but that dont work

```
pizzaTypes = {
    "Hawaiian":"$8.50", "Pepperoni":"$8.50", "Simply Cheese":"$8.50", "Ham & Cheese":"$8.50", "Beef & Onion":"$8.50", "Cheesy Garlic":"$8.50", "BBQ Pork & Onion":"$8.50", "Mr. Wedge":"$13.50", "Apricot Chicken":"$13.50", "Cranberry & Chicken":"$13.50", "BBQ Meatlovers":"$13.50", "Godfather":"$13.50"
    }
```

this above is my dictionary. Thanks

Comment: Can you include an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is actually.

```
for x,y in pizzaTypes.items():
    print(x,y)
```

This means that for every key, and every value, it would print separately, so your output would be:

```
BBQ Pork & Onion $8.50
Apricot Chicken $13.50
Ham & Cheese $8.50
Mr. Wedge $13.50
Hawaiian $8.50
BBQ Meatlovers $13.50
Pepperoni $8.50
Beef & Onion $8.50
Godfather $13.50
Cheesy Garlic $8.50
Simply Cheese $8.50
Cranberry & Chicken $13.50
```

Comment: Note: for python2 you need to do pizzaTypes.iteritems() or pizzaTypes.viewitems() (viewitems is 2.7+)

Answer (score 2):

You can also pretty print the dictionary, printing the dict key-value pairs in separate lines:

```
import pprint
pizzaTypes = {
    "Hawaiian":"$8.50", "Pepperoni":"$8.50", "Simply Cheese":"$8.50", "Ham & Cheese":"$8.50", "Beef & Onion":"$8.50", "Cheesy Garlic":"$8.50", "BBQ Pork & Onion":"$8.50", "Mr. Wedge":"$13.50", "Apricot Chicken":"$13.50", "Cranberry & Chicken":"$13.50", "BBQ Meatlovers":"$13.50", "Godfather":"$13.50"
    }
pprint.pprint(pizzaTypes)

#Output:
{'Apricot Chicken': '$13.50',
 'BBQ Meatlovers': '$13.50',
 'BBQ Pork & Onion': '$8.50',
 'Beef & Onion': '$8.50',
 'Cheesy Garlic': '$8.50',
 'Cranberry & Chicken': '$13.50',
 'Godfather': '$13.50',
 'Ham & Cheese': '$8.50',
 'Hawaiian': '$8.50',
 'Mr. Wedge': '$13.50',
 'Pepperoni': '$8.50',
 'Simply Cheese': '$8.50'}
```